# Performance of a socket

Tags: tcp, udp, layer4

What is the difference between the following scenario's. And is there any performance differ due to this.

Consider a server provide 5 services like web, mail, file, app and ssh :

1. Each service and its corresponding port is bound with A different
   socket (Individual socket for each service).
2. A single socket is bound with all the services corresponding to the
   port it runs (common socket for all services).

Comment: It's not possible to bind a socket to more than one port.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot bind a socket to more than one port.

Answer (score 0):

A socket consists of an IP address and port combination.

Your OS is only going to allow a single application to bind to a single port on a given transport-layer protocol. If you have a single application which can run all the services, then that application can bind to a single port for all the services, but multiple applications cannot bind to a single port on the same transport-layer protocol.

Whether or not performance would be better with a single application running all those services on a single port is going to depend on the application, and it would be off-topic here. The fact is that each of the services you list has a separate, well-known port, and it would be awkward to use a different port than the well-known port for any of those services since clients would assume the well-known ports are being used.